# Yesod build error because of the duplicate definition for symbol "hsprimitive_memcpy"

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I followed "Yesod quick start guide" to install Yesod in Windows 10.
But, when I issued the `stack build` command, it failed.

#### Environment

- Windows 10 (64bits)
- `stack-0.1.5` (for Windows10 64bits)
- Haskell Platform 7.10.2-a (from HaskellPlatform-7.10.2-a-x86_64-setup.exe)

#### alex-3.1.4.log

```
GHC runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   hsprimitive_memcpy
whilst processing object file
   C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\stack\snapshots\x86_64-windows\lts-3.8\7.10.2\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2\primitive-0.6.1.0-5Jnw7oEuYtM9dmKXelGXVb\HSprimitive-0.6.1.0-5Jnw7oEuYtM9dmKXelGXVb.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.2 for x86_64-unknown-mingw32):
    loadObj "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\stack\\snapshots\\x86_64-windows\\lts-3.8\\7.10.2\\lib\\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2\\primitive-0.6.1.0-5Jnw7oEuYtM9dmKXelGXVb\\HSprimitive-0.6.1.0-5Jnw7oEuYtM9dmKXelGXVb.o": failed
```

Comment: This kind of error usually arises from having two versions of the same package installed, presumably the `primitive` package in this case. But I thought that was supposed to be impossible with stack...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the cause of the error were the duplicated GHC installation. 
Thanks for @Reid comment, I realized that I installed Haskel Platform from exe file before and I also installed GHC through stack by folloing the guide.

I unisatlled GHC of Haskel Platform and executed 'stack setup' command. 
Then, I executed 'stack build' command and it seemed worked. 
I still have problems with the 'stack build' command, but I solved this issue.